# jQuery accordion not working on site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I wanted to try and use an accordion feature on my website, I copied and pasted the source code on the website http://jqueryui.com/ nothing happens. My browser just produces text without the accordion feature. Please help, am using Microsoft expression to edit my code.

Comment: make sure u included the UI-libraries in your page, Post codes so that we can give you precise solutions

Comment: When I run my code, I Keep getting the error, File not found../../../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and File not found: resources/demos/style.css

Comment: please find my answer, comment there if u need any further help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is with path you given for the resources

give complete path of links (starting with http) you provided for js and css files

if it doesn't work. go for below steps

Download those files(hit link in browser--> right click--> save as -->)

Put every downloaded js and css inside the same folder where your HTML/JSP file present and just give the file names without any path in the `src` and `href` attributes for `js` and `CSS` files respectively

This will work for sure

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Holla holla
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Namaste
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   adaab
    </p>

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Annie you didn't provided you complete code and what was the errors you were getting. Now use and experiment this code to fulfill your configurations

Comment: When I run  my code and/or your code at the top, I Keep getting the error,                                                                  File not found../../../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

and

File not found: resources/demos/style.css

Comment: Just do a thing @Annie ... just take a snapshot of your code where you are   including these files and getting the errors

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup, and reading exactly what you wrote - you copied and pasted the code...

Did that include both stylesheet and script links?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you did that - then I would use Firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) to debug the page you are developing and see if there are any problems with your links.

Comment: Yes I did and these are the errors am getting                    File not found../../../../../code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css  and File not found: resources/demos/style.css